# Functionalizing few lines of code with ant macrodef

Tags: function, ant, macrodef

I am trying to "function"alize few lines of ant-code using `macrodef`. But its resulting in error like :

```
copy doesn't support the nested "my-macro" element.
```

If I "inline" definition of my-macro of adding filterchian within copy-task it works.

My test target looks like this -

```
<target name="copy-files">
        <sequential>
            <copy todir="abc" >
                <fileset dir="xyz">
                    <!--needy includes/excludes -->
                </fileset>
                <my-macro/>
            </copy>
        </sequential>
 </target>
```

And my-macro looks like this:

```
 <macrodef name="my-macro">
        <sequential>
            <filterchain>
                <fixcrlf includes="**" eol="lf"/>
            </filterchain>
        </sequential>

    </macrodef>
```

Code which works (inlined-one ) looks like :

```
<target name="copy-files">
        <sequential>
            <copy todir="abc" >
                <fileset dir="xyz">
                    <!--needy includes/excludes -->
                </fileset>
                <filterchain>
                <fixcrlf includes="**" eol="lf"/>
            </filterchain>
          </copy>
 </sequential></target>
```

Comment: Can you also show the code that works?

Comment: <target name="copy-files">
        <sequential>
            <copy todir="abc" >
                <fileset dir="xyz">
                    <!--needy includes/excludes -->
                </fileset>
                <filterchain>
                <fixcrlf includes="**" eol="lf"/>
            </filterchain>
          </copy>
 </sequential></target>

Comment: @coolcfan Have edited in my question - showing working-inlined code

Answer (score 1):

The copy task doesn't accept a nested macro element, thats what the errormessage says.
Put the whole copy stuff into your macrodef, f.e. :

```
<macrodef name="my-macro">
 <attribute name="dest"/>
 <attribute name="fsdir"/>
 <attribute name="fsincludes"/>
 <attribute name="fsexcludes"/>
 <attribute name="fixincl"/>
 <sequential>
  <copy todir="@dest}">
   <fileset dir="@{fsdir}">
    <include name="@{fsincludes}"/>
    <exclude name="@{fsexcludes}"/>
   </fileset>
   <filterchain>
    <fixcrlf includes="@{fixincl}" eol="lf"/>
   </filterchain>
  </copy>
 </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

**-- EDIT --**
If number of filesets varies, remove the fsincludes and fsexcludes attribute if not valid for all filesets and use element like that :

```
 <macrodef name="my-macro">
  <attribute name="dest"/>
  <element name="fs" description="nested filesets"/>
  <attribute name="fixincl"/>
  <sequential>
   <copy todir="@dest}">
     <!-- 1-n nested filesets) -->
     <fs/>
    <filterchain>
     <fixcrlf includes="@{fixincl}" eol="lf"/>
    </filterchain>
   </copy>
  </sequential>
 </macrodef>


 <my-macro dest="C:/whatever" fixincl="**">
   <fs>
     <fileset dir="." includes="**/*.foo"/>
     <fileset dir="../foo" includes="**/*.xml"/>
     <!-- ... -->
   </fs>
 </my-macro>
```

**-- EDIT --**
To copy a single file with nested fileset use :

```
<fileset file="C:/somepath/some.file"/>
```

**-- EDIT --**
If you need other copysteps with file tofile, you may use another element if that is sufficient:

```
<macrodef name="my-macro">
 <attribute name="dest"/>
 <element name="copyfiles" description="nested copy"/>
 <element name="fs" description="nested filesets"/>
 <attribute name="fixincl"/>
 <sequential>

  <copy todir="@dest}">
    <!-- 1-n nested filesets) -->
    <fs/>
   <filterchain>
    <fixcrlf includes="@{fixincl}" eol="lf"/>
   </filterchain>
  </copy>

  <copyfiles/>

 </sequential>
</macrodef>

<my-macro dest="C:/whatever" fixincl="**">
 <fs>
  <fileset dir="." includes="**/*.foo"/>
  <fileset dir="../foo" includes="**/*.xml"/>
  <!-- ... -->
 </fs>
 <copyfiles>
  <copy file="..." tofile="..."/>
  <!-- ... --> 
  </copyfiles>
</my-macro>
```

Normally for bulk renaming of files a [mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html) is used.
After all if it gets more complicated you should consider scripting with [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) or [write your own Ant Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html#writingowntask).

Comment: I did thought about this design but unfortunately it does not fit current problem : coz `copy` ant task is used with different type of options like `flatten` attribute set to true/false etc. .. And also # of `fileset` occurance also varies along with # of include/exclude pattern. Hence the reason why I am only trying to put common lines to a macro & re-use within copy task

Comment: Option of using `element` within `macrodef` is handy for addressing varying # of fileset. Thanks for sharing this.But Still I don't see a easy way to handle different attribute set support within copy task to make it fully work, f.e : I can't use same macro when its just file-copy with `file` and `tofile` attributes, as it would be desinged to work on dir.s . Other common attributes can still be parameterized & passed by setting to appropriate value. Is there any other way where I can extend/simulate the behaviour of 'function' by writing some custom class?

Comment: Wow, Your latest edit simplified to one more level. As my current project is complecated in terms of having a different copy styles/strategy : though above option solves copying single file with fileset , in the project intentionally & for a purpose `tofile` attribure is used - as with copy over to destination we copy with different file name. f.e : `x/y/some.abc.profile` to `x/abc/y/some.profile` respecting project deployment path & above varying value gets framed dynamically within a loop based on some calculation with propertyselectors....

Answer (score 0):

Rebse's answer already shows what you should go with `<macrodef>`, and here's some explanation.

**Copy Task**

`<copy>`, `<macrodef>`, `<sequential>` are Ant tasks. Each Ant task is backed with Java code. Most of Java classes of built-in Ant tasks are under `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs`, e.g. [Copy.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.ant/ant/1.9.3/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Copy.java) is the backend of `<copy>` task.

The nested elements of a task is handled by the task's Java code. For `<copy>` task, it's code in Copy.java (or other classes it depends on) handling the nested elements.

You will see in Copy.java methods named with `createFilterChain`, `addFileset`, `createMapper` and others. That's why `<copy>` supports fileset, filterchain, mapper and other nested elements stated in [Copy's manual page](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html).

**Macrodef**

> This defines a new task using a  nested task as a template.

Macrodef is a way to define an Ant task without coding in Java. It turns its nested Ant xml lines into a new task, which works the same way as other Ant tasks.

Obviously, you should not just put a `<filterchain>` in `<macrodef>`, as `<filterchain>` is not an Ant task, but an [Ant type](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html).

Comment: Thanks @coolcfan for sharing implementation-details of `macrodef` working/support. As I added in the comment below to @Rebse 's answer I am only trying to achieve "function"alizing part. Is there an equivalent type to macrodef for achieving this in ant ?

Comment: `<macrodef>` is designed to enable users to declare new tasks within the build file -- similar tasks: `<presetdef>` and `<scriptdef>`. You want to take things in common from "copy" usages, but a call to `<copy>` with `<fileset>` and a call to `<copy>` with just `file` param are just two different logics in Ant. If you want to share a `<filterchain>` or `<mapper>` in many `<copy>` instances, you can go with `refid`.